# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: java, swing

can someone please tell me what is the problem?
the class Camera is extend Jpanel

the code:

```
    public class Main extends JFrame {
       public static Image image;
    //sort the cameras by their heights.
        public static void main(String [] args){
            image = new Image(400,400,"test");
            Camera c=new Camera(100, 100, (Math.PI)/4, 0, 200,200,Math.PI,Color.MAGENTA);
            image.addCamera(c);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            int width= image.getWidth();
            int length = image.getLength();
            f.setSize(width, length);
            f.add(new Main());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       //Sets the title of the frame
            f.setTitle(image.getName());
            f.setVisible(true);

        }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("in the paint");
        Vector<Camera> cameras = image.getCameras();
        for(int i=0;i<cameras.size();i++){
            cameras.get(i).paintComponent(g);
         }
    `enter code here`}
```

in the class Camera there the function paintCompoment,
but the result is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a         container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:483)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
    at CameraPack.Main.main(Main.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: You're trying to add a component that extends from `Window` to another `Window`...can't do that.  What does `Image` and `Camera` extend from?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `JFrame` (your Main class) to another `JFrame` (f). That won't fly, since they're both `Windows`.

Answer (score 2):

add() function of JFrame takes a Component argument and that argument must not be an instance of Window.

So in your add() method somewhere in between it calls `checkNotAWindow(component);`. In your case component is another JFrame.

```
/**
 * Checks that the component is not a Window instance.
 */
private void checkNotAWindow(Component comp){
    if (comp instanceof Window) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adding a window to a container");
    }
}
```

Now `JFrame extends Frame` and `Frame extends Window` which makes your component(JFrame) instance of window which is why you get `adding a window to a container` exception.